# Ethernet network disconnected but the cable is actually plugged in

Tags: networking, networkmanager, ethernet, internet

I have recently installed GalliumOS alpha on my Acer Chromebook 14. WiFi works flawlessly, but I can't get the Ethernet connection to work as network manager says "disconnected" under Ethernet Network.

The output from ifconfig when I have the cable connected is the following:

```
enx00e04c695951: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

ether 00:e0:4c:69:59:51 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)

RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)

RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0

TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)

TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536

inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0

inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>

loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)

RX packets 838 bytes 82846 (82.8 KB)

RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0

TX packets 838 bytes 82846 (82.8 KB)

TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

inet 10.5.18.248 netmask 255.255.248.0 broadcast 10.5.23.255

inet6 fe80::97cf:c04d:9612:da28 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>

ether 7c:b0:c2:5c:2b:e6 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)

RX packets 75936 bytes 95893928 (95.8 MB)

RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0

TX packets 23861 bytes 3623765 (3.6 MB)

TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

While, if I disconnect it, the output is:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536

inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0

inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>

loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)

RX packets 838 bytes 82846 (82.8 KB)

RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0

TX packets 838 bytes 82846 (82.8 KB)

TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

inet 10.5.18.248 netmask 255.255.248.0 broadcast 10.5.23.255

inet6 fe80::97cf:c04d:9612:da28 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>

ether 7c:b0:c2:5c:2b:e6 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)

RX packets 76079 bytes 95913145 (95.9 MB)

RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0

TX packets 23981 bytes 3646301 (3.6 MB)

TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

In /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf the following content is present:

```
[main]

plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]

managed=true

[device]

wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is there a DHCP server running on your network? Have you tried to assign a static IP to the wired interface?

Comment: @Panki No, there is not. I will try assigning a static IP: which IP should I use?

Comment: That depends on the network you want to join. You need to know the network address and subnet mask.